# Typescript decorator for function, not method. Possible?

Tags: typescript, decorator

I'm trying to add a custom TypeScript decorator in a function which is not included in a class and it seems that the compiler is complaining no matter what I do.

Any thoughts? Is it possible?

Comment: Decorators for functions are currently not supported, but TS follows the ES decorators proposal which is work-in-progress, see https://github.com/iddan/proposal-function-expression-decorators/issues/3

Comment: Hi Until now this feature it not included yet, currently decorators can only be added to classes, methods, and properties, this is still blocked by the lack of JavaScript ability to do that., you can follow the issue discussion https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7318

Comment: Also see https://github.com/iddan/proposal-function-expression-decorators

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> add a custom TypeScript decorator in a function

Not to a raw function. The main issue is dealing with `hoisting` of functions. Any attempt to wrap a function in another function breaks the hoist.

**Support Targets**

> A *Decorator* is a special kind of declaration that can be attached to a class declaration, method, accessor, property, or parameter. Decorators use the form `@expression`, where `expression` must evaluate to a function that will be called at runtime with information about the decorated declaration.

Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorators

Comment: github link is out of date

Comment: @ZoltanMagyar thanks. It was just the markdown source for the handbook and provided little value (only useful if someone wanted to edit the handbook), so removed 

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how the *hoisting* rule prevents decorating general functions? I am coming from Python where decorators of any kind are prevalent and very interested in learning these differences.

Comment: @Dummmy In Python, function definitions are executed in order, just like normal assignments. In JavaScript, as MDN docs say,  functions defined via `function` are loaded into memory before the program is run: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

If you want to something similar to a Python decorator, you can just do: `const foo = yourDecorator(function (...) {...})`.

Comment: @decorator-factory name checks out ;). Also, to improve upon you comment, function level decorators can be implemented as, 
```const outer = (fn) => {
  let var = 0; // variables you need to be available in closure
return (...args) => {
  // decorator code
  return fn(..args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't possible because the method decorator use the `PropertyDescriptor` and this one is only possible to use in classes.

But, there is a lib that you can use the method decorators in functions, but without the syntax `@myDecorator`. The decorator has the same syntax, you can use exist method decorators in functions

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pure-function-decorator

But, instead this:

```
class Somethind {
  @log
  myMethod() { //....
```

You can use in this way

```
const myFunction = fnDecorator([log], () => { /*....*/});
```

And has the same result