# Is it possible to use a return value of the function in decorator function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I would like to use output value of a function as an input of decorator that the function is using. For example, something like that:

```
function dec(otherFuncOutput: string) {
  console.log(otherFuncOutput)
}

@dec
function otherFunc(): string {
  const otherFuncOutput: string = "output";
  return otherFuncOutput;
}
```

What is the right way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript decorators [can be applied to a class declaration, method, accessor, property, or parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorators) but [not plain functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518913/typescript-decorator-for-function-not-method-possible), so I'm going to assume you want to do this with a class method.

So do do this, you need to examine the property descriptor, take the function value it describes and replace it with a new function that calls the original function and does something with it's output.

```
function dec(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
  // Check of the decorated property is a function
  if (typeof descriptor.value === 'function') {
    // The function that we are going to wrap
    const declaredFn = descriptor.value

    // Provide a new function for this property that wraps the original function
    descriptor.value = () => {
      // Call the method with `this` set the object with the method,
      // in case that matters.
      const result = declaredFn.apply(target)

      // Do the thing you want with the result
      console.log(result)

      // Return the result from the origin function
      return result
    }
  }
}

class A {
  @dec
  otherFunc(): string {
    const otherFuncOutput = 'output'
    return otherFuncOutput
  }
}

new A().otherFunc() // logs "output"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYQBRQIYCcDmqUAXItmAJ4A0iADrnLarlBQNKoWkDOUuMYfDTTcI-WlDi5SABQZMWFACKpR4ybgCUiAN4AoRIgD0RxAGEAFugDWiOMERQrKdFOxRUyOvOatEMbjJEUEhYBAN-BywKJnsXNRgJKQA6ADdsABsQVEQAXnzEAHIQ6HgwQu19Q0MTRAAVZxKwpCd3RAB3HLwc-DgBfEc4DtxsWgjDCAReFwgM7uQAMSRc+LFEjTTM7L1x41M5OFSYNCCwVHbg8FKEYKlHCwDvRl8Ke7b2kdpApxypGHwBJlLqEyrsRGskrhNlkcisMNpcgA+XS7GqmMyZDL3HIAWyIFjgXnaMCciAABk4AmTENwiNi7AAjABW6CgHRJFnpeKchKoqL2-iQEGwtLebJx7g8uG4yX5kzA01wqhAGTZKzQs3mS2So1oGQoWDwhCgmh21WqtSUQx+936iAocBAHXIbOJpJtSu4KqgcqmcAyqGSGTg+Awnu9pv5tQASkQQLgWs5w6rggwcfS-gCkE1QebDEqoPGkMmfeaAL4RCsVvSa7iBACCKMMAAENRE4D9cAsrvCeHw7VVqvLph2rF2rgB5EBQWjTvJFR0z6eFXYFot2TvdyBTpelxBVnZnC71+HJUfMLeYbS1YP4QIAIkXs6g970QA)

Answer (score 2):

After the right given answer by Alex I also found how to use it if decorated function has input arguments:

```
function logger(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const original = descriptor.value;
    if (typeof original == 'function') {
    descriptor.value = function(...args) {
      var result = original.apply(this, args);
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    }
  }
  return descriptor;
}

class C {
    @logger
    add(x: number, y:number ): number {
        return x + y;
    }
}

const c = new C();
c.add(1, 2);
```