# Most concise way to memoize a TypeScript function without using module scope

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am looking for a way to memoize a function without relying on a wrapping function. I had the idea to use the function object as the cache like so:

```
function getDocumentRegistry() {
  const self = getDocumentRegistry
  if (self.documentRegistry) return self.documentRegistry
  return self.documentRegistry = ts.createDocumentRegistry()
}

function main() {
  const foo = getDocumentRegistry()
}
```

There is a lot of repetition here. Is there are simpler way? I want to keep the code very readable.

---

UPDATE: So far I came up with this improvement.

```
function getDocumentRegistry() {
  const self = getDocumentRegistry
  return self.value ?? (self.value = ts.createDocumentRegistry())
}
```

---

Using a wrapper/helper and module scope:

```
function memoize(fn) {
  return fn.value ?? (fn.value = fn())
}

function getDocumentRegistry() {
  return ts.createDocumentRegistry()
}

const getDocumentRegistryCached = memoize(getDocumentRegistry)
```

Comment: Well, your function could be condensed to `function getDocumentRegistry() { return getDocumentRegistry.cache ?? (getDocumentRegistry.cache = ts.createDocumentRegistry); }`

Comment: I see with your edit you came up with a similar approach, but you don't need the `self` assignment. That being said though, we're talking about a handful of lines of non-obsfucated code. How much is readability really a concern here?

Comment: Thanks. I like the `self` because it makes it more generic and slightly more DRY. If I'm going to use this pattern all over the place I think it makes it easier to understand what is going on. And there is no line-wrapping.

Comment: "going to use this pattern all over the place" and "DRY" is kind of a contradiction. What's up with *not using a wrapping function*? Where does this requirement come from?

Comment: I mean the function body is DRY (function name written once instead of twice). The user can understand exactly what is going on in the above function - if I added a helper with a setter callback, it becomes harder to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I also wonder if there is a better naming pattern? Like `getSharedDocumentRegistry` / `getDocumentRegistryCached` / `getDocumentRegistrySingleton`

Comment: @Thomas I actually think a wrapper might be better because of single-responsibility-pattern. It should not both: (1) manage it's uniqueness and (2) perform its function.

Comment: [Your use case](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/447190/projectional-javascript-editor-while-maintaining-compatibility) still doesn't really make sense. (Why did you delete that question, btw?)

Comment: @Bergi Deleted because it felt too complex to explain in proper detail for such a forum. If everything is just functions (no module scope), then I could combine all the functions into a single file, and it's still editable in a normal text editor. It would allow creating files containing any subset of functions (something like a temporary workspace). As soon as you have module scope (and module-level imports), you have name clashes in such a situation.

Comment: @vaughan I'm not sure if you already responded to my comments there before you deleted the question - I can no longer access it - but I still don't get it. If everything is declared in the global scope in a single file, surely there's more name clashes than when using modules with unique identifiers? And I don't understand how that is related to editing (by file, right in the database, in a single file, or in arbitrary workspaces), unless you assume that each workspace has its own scope.

Comment: The functions are mirrored to another file on disk...which you can also edit - containing only that function. So a change to a file in a "workspace file" will update its source of truth. There can be many workspace files. If TS had a `module {}` scope, then this would be perfect for me...but it doesn't. Some name mangling may be necessary with functions, yes.

Comment: I just realized https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html might help me...

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to declare the wrapped function as a separate variable with its own name. Just use an anonymous function expression:

```
const getDocumentRegistry = memoize(function() {
  return ts.createDocumentRegistry();
});
```

Unless you need to use the uncached version as well in some cases, don't add a `Cached` suffix to the name to distinguish them, the caller won't care - it's the responsibility of the implementer to cache results or not.

In this particular case, you can further simplify using an arrow function, or no function expression at all:

```
const getDocumentRegistry = memoize(() => ts.createDocumentRegistry());
const getDocumentRegistry = memoize(ts.createDocumentRegistry);
```

The syntactically nicest way to write this would be using decorators, [unfortunately that is not possible for `function`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37518913/1048572).

Comment: >  it's the responsibility of the implementer to cache results or not: I initially thought about this...but I don't think its really a cache. Its just a shared data structure, a singleton. I think its better to say exactly how its shared though...so at present its effectively global, so: `getGlobalDocumentRegistry`. This reduces ambiguity in how it's used.

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't read that properly. If it's shared state, it is important to point out in the name.